# How to switch branch when filename case changes?

Tags: git

1. I have a branch `development` with a file `Config.json`.
2. I am creating a new branch `new_development`, where I rename `Config.json` to `config.json` and commit.
3. I switch back to `development` to see how some things were made in that branch. No errors.
4. I switch to `new_development` to continue work on new stuff. It shows an error:

> error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
>
> ```
>    Config.json
> ```
>
> Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
>
> Aborting

The file is actually in git.

I have this git config:

```
[core]
    ignorecase = false
```

How do I make branches switching work when the same files have different case?

Comment: Do commit by -am option,

    `git commit -am "config file name changed"`

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that it's not under version control "error: The following *untracked working tree files* would be overwritten by checkout".  I'm not quite sure how you ended up this way.  What does `git ls-tree HEAD .` show on the branch and directory where `Config.json` is located?  Do you see `Config.json` in the listing?  If not, then it's not under version control (and not simply a case issue).

Comment: Why do you have `ignoreCase = false`?  It looks like you're on a case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: If I had to guess I would say that `Config.json` is not committed to your development branch. There is not really enough info here yet. Can you print out `git ls-files` (lists all the files in your repo) and `git status` on both of your branches? To swap to your new branch you may need to delete Config.Json (so just delete/copy it elsewhere for the moment), then you should at least be able to swap branch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> How do I make branches switching work when the same files have different case?

Change `core.ignoreCase` back to `true`.

You are on a case *insensitive* filesystem; git uses the `core.ignoreCase` setting to indicate that.  It is configured when you create a repository (either via `git init` or by `git clone`): git looks at your filesystem to determine whether it's case sensitive or not, and caches that information (in the `core.ignoreCase` setting) so that it doesn't have to do this lookup for every operation.

This is not a setting that is meant for you to change.

With `core.ignoreCase = false`, on a case *insensitive* filesystem:

```
% git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob 257cc5642cb1a054f08cc83f2d943e56fd3ebe99    foo
% git ls-tree branch
100644 blob bcc9cdfd113753edf279e92afd622b0f3bb05fbc    FOO
% git checkout branch
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
    FOO
Please move or remove them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

This is because I've told git that my filesystem *is* case sensitive.  It looks at the tree that I'm trying to check out, sees that there's a file called `FOO` that is *not* in my current `HEAD` tree, and then looks on disk to see if there's an untracked working file with the same name.  It `stats` the file `FOO` (which is really the file `foo`, since we're on a case insensitive filesystem) and realizes that you have an untracked file in the working directory.

Except, of course, you don't.  You have the file `foo`.

If I correct this, setting `core.ignoreCase` to reflect the reality of my filesystem, then I can switch branches properly:

```
% git config core.ignoreCase true
% git checkout branch
Switched to branch 'branch'
% git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob bcc9cdfd113753edf279e92afd622b0f3bb05fbc    FOO
```

Comment: Actually I set that to false manually. I am on MacOS. I will turn it back.

Comment: I set `core.ignoreCase` to true, but i still can't switch to another branch (win10)